# Force array to maintain type 'double' when concatenating multiple mixed numeric type values in matlab

Tags: matlab

In matlab, is there a way to force an array to maintain the type `double` when concatenating various numeric types such as `uint64` and `uint32`?

For example, the following code produces this:

```
>> timestamp = uint64(12);    % 1x1 uint64
>> t_id = uint32(3);          % 1x1 uint32
>> t_value = double(1.5);     % 1x1 double

>> frame = [ timestamp, t_id, t_value ];    % 1x3 uint64

frame =

          12           3           2
```

when I want:

```
frame =

  12.000000000000000   3.000000000000000   1.500000000000000
```

I'm aware that I can convert the variables using `double()`, but in my application the array is much larger, and many elements are integer types. Is there a way to do this without manually converting every integer?

If it helps, the variables are the fields of an array of `struct`s in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily write a function to do the conversion for you. The following functions do that. Note, however, that they use cells (in order to allow an arbitrary number of inputs, by means of [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)), and so it they may not be very fast.

1. If you want to concatenate **horizontally** (as in your example):

   ```
   function out = horzcatdouble(varargin)
   v = cellfun(@double, varargin, 'uniformoutput', false);
   out = [v{:}];
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   >> horzcatdouble( uint16([1 2]), 3.7 )
   ans =
       1.0000    2.0000    3.7000
   ```
2. If you want to **specify the dimension** along which to concatenate (as you do with the [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) function):

   ```
   function out = catdouble(dim, varargin)
   v = cellfun(@double, varargin, 'uniformoutput', false);
   out = cat(dim, v{:});
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   >> catdouble(2, uint16([1 2]), 3.7 )
   ans =
       1.0000    2.0000    3.7000
   ```

Comment: Yep, I figured this is the case. I asked on the off chance that there was an implicit way to do this because execution time is of concern for me. I will be working with data sets that contain ~100,000 - ~10,000,000 structs that need some form of the above. With that said, this solution is within 100 microseconds of just converting it manually so I'm pretty pleased with that. Thanks!